# BPF Ring Buffer Invalid Argument (-22)?

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I wanted to use eBPF's latest map, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF`, but I can't find much information online on how I can use it, so I am just doing some trial-and-error here. I defined and used it like this:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") r_buf = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF,
    .max_entries = 1 << 2,
};

SEC("lsm/task_alloc")
int BPF_PROG(task_alloc, struct task_struct *task, unsigned long clone_flags) {
    uint32_t pid  = task->pid;
    bpf_ringbuf_output(&r_buf, &pid, sizeof(uint32_t), 0); //stores the pid value to the ring buffer
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the following error when running:

```
libbpf: map 'r_buf': failed to create: Invalid argument(-22)
libbpf: failed to load object 'bpf_example_kern'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'bpf_example_kern': -22
```

It seems like `libbpf` does not recognize `BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF`? I cloned the latest `libbpf` from GitHub and did `make` and `make install`. I am using Linux 5.8.0 kernel.

**UPDATE**: The issue seems to be resolved if I changed the `max_entries` to something like 4096 * 64, but I don't know why this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the problem is in the size of BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF (max_entries attribute in libbpf map definition). It has to be a multiple of a memory page (which is 4096 bytes at least on most popular platforms). So that explains why it all worked when you specified 64 * 4096.

BTW, if you'd like to see some examples of using it, I'd start with BPF selftests:

- user-space part: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/prog_tests/ringbuf.c
- kernel (BPF) part: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/progs/test_ringbuf.c